# implement splitView programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to create a splitView in Android programmatically. This feature is completely new to me. After some research, I realized the Fragment has to be used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleReaderFragment"
            android:id="@+id/viewer"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am wondering, is the LinearLayout the best option for a layout? Secondly is it possible to add UI parts like buttons, pickers onto the fragment programmatically as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any layout with Fragments, totally depends on your requirement.

Yes you can add views like Buttons etc to Fragment programmatically. Declare the layout of the  Fragment to be a Layout.

One example of adding views programmatically --- R.layout.main could be a LinearLayout with no child views

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup mViewGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    Button mButton = new Button(getActivity());
    mButton.setLayoutParameters(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    mViewGroup.add(mButton);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajdeep, as regards adding the views, can you provide an example please? Thanks.

Comment: Rajdeep thanks, however I meant adding the view to the Fragment. Your example seems to be adding the view to the layout. Please advise.

Comment: Every fragment can have its layout. In this case Fragments layout could be R.layout.main

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use fragment layout or building application in lower android version which does not have fragment support, in this case you can get the split view by calling two separate XML files in one activity. Just but build two xml as per requirement on left and right. Small example

`LinearLayout layoutMain = new LinearLayout(this);
    layoutMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    setContentView(layoutMain);
    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout layoutLeft = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
        R.layout.firstxml, null);
    RelativeLayout layoutRight = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
        R.layout.secondxml, null);`

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutMain.addView(layoutLeft, 100, 100);
layoutMain.addView(layoutRight, relParam);
```

}
`